# Android Game Screen Limits

Tags: java, android, screen, android-studio

I'm trying to do a game but I'm stuck. I have a player and I move it with the buttons but I can't make the player stop when it reachs the screen limits. What am I doing wrong?

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

Button arriba, abajo, derecha, izquierda;
private Juego juego;
private Bitmap personaje;
private Sprite sprite;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    juego = (Juego) findViewById(R.id.customView);
    personaje = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bad1);
    sprite = new Sprite(juego, personaje);

    arriba = (Button)findViewById(R.id.arriba);
    abajo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.abajo);
    derecha = (Button)findViewById(R.id.derecha);
    izquierda = (Button)findViewById(R.id.izquierda);

    arriba.setOnClickListener(this);
    arriba.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    abajo.setOnClickListener(this);
    abajo.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    derecha.setOnClickListener(this);
    derecha.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    izquierda.setOnClickListener(this);
    izquierda.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    juego.parar();
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    juego.mover();
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.arriba:
            juego.arriba();
            break;
        case R.id.abajo:
            juego.abajo();
            break;
        case R.id.derecha:
            juego.derecha();
            break;
        case R.id.izquierda:
            juego.izquierda();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Juego:

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView{

private Bitmap personaje;
private Sprite sprite;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    personaje = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bad1);
    sprite = new Sprite(this, personaje);
}

public void mover(){
    sprite.mover();
    invalidate();
}

public void parar(){
    sprite.parar();
    invalidate();
}

public void arriba(){
    sprite.dir= 3;
    invalidate();
}

public void abajo(){
    sprite.dir= 0;
    invalidate();
}

public void derecha(){
    sprite.dir= 2;
    invalidate();
}

public void izquierda(){
    sprite.dir= 1;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    invalidate();
}
}
```

Sprite:

```
private static final int Horizontal = 4;
private static final int Vertical = 3;
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
private Juego juego;
private Bitmap personaje;
private int currentFrame = 0;
private int ancho;
private int alto;
int dir = 2;
private int velocidadx = 0;
private int velocidady = 0;

long fps;
private long timeThisFrame;
private long lastFrameChangeTime = 0;
private int frameLengthInMilliseconds = 100;
int cantFrames = 3;
boolean playing = false;

public Sprite(Juego juego, Bitmap personaje){
    this.juego = juego;
    this.personaje = personaje;
    this.ancho = personaje.getWidth() / Vertical;
    this.alto = personaje.getHeight() / Horizontal;
}

public void mover(){
    playing = true;
}
public void parar(){
    playing = false;
}

private void update() {

    if (playing) {

        long startFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (startFrame > lastFrameChangeTime + frameLengthInMilliseconds) {
            lastFrameChangeTime = startFrame;
            currentFrame++;
            if (currentFrame >= cantFrames) {

                currentFrame = 0;
            }
        }

        long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
        if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
            fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
        }

        if (dir== 0 && y < juego.getHeight() - alto - velocidady) {
            velocidadx = 0;
            velocidady = 5;
        }
        if (dir== 1 && x > ancho){
            velocidadx = -5;
            velocidady = 0;
        }
        if (dir== 2 && x < juego.getWidth() - velocidadx){
            velocidadx = 5;
            velocidady = 0;
        }
        if (dir== 3 && y > alto){
            velocidadx = 0;
            velocidady = -5;
        }

        x = x + velocidadx;
        y = y + velocidady;
    }
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    update();
    int srcX = currentFrame * ancho;
    int srcY = alto * dir;
    Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + ancho, srcY + alto);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + ancho, y + alto);
    canvas.drawBitmap(personaje, src, dst, null);
}
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? No one is going to debug your code.

Comment: Are you asking about how to stop your character at the screen edges?

Comment: yes, i want that the character stops when reach the screen edges